# Codeigniter Session can't save after redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a project that i developed using CodeIgniter on localhost in Windows using XAMPP. This project is almost done and **running well in my server and localhost on my first laptop (i developed on my first laptop). But, when i tried to running this project on my second laptop, this project is lost / remove the session when page loading / redirect.** Whereas the session data has been received and generated well before the page refresh/ redirect.

**Note: I use same source code on my first and second laptop**

I dont know why. I've tried the solution of problems in stackoverflow friends but dont get a work solution.

**My Autoload**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','pagination','bcrypt','form_validation');
```

**My Config** session and cookie by default

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

**My controller**

```
public function auth()
{
    $username=$this->input->post('username');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');

    $this->login_m->set_username($username);
    $query = $this->login_m->login();
    if ($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        if ($password == $this->bcrypt->check_password($password,$row->password)) {    
            $data_login= array(
            'username'=>$row->username,
            'id_user'=>$row->id_user,
            'nama'=>$row->nama,
            'akses'=>$row->akses
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data_login);
            $akses = $this->session->userdata('akses');
            if ($akses=='super admin' or $akses=='admin') {
                redirect('dashboard');
            }elseif ($akses=='user') {
                    redirect('home');
            }       
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek nip, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek nip, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
    }
}
```

**My Model**

```
public function login()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * from por_user where username = ?";
        return $this->db->query($query,array($this->get_username()));
    }
```

**Note: I use same source code on my first and second laptop**

When i am print the session after redirect the result is **null**

Can anyone help me? 
*pardon my english* :D Thankyou

Comment: Do you have any users in your database??

Answer (score 0):

You need to set save path something like

application/cache/session/

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';
```

Permission 0700